# Necesito conectar firebase notifications con yii2

Tags: firebase, yii2, firebase-messaging

necesito crear una vista en yii2 para poder enviar notificaciones a los dispositivos android que se hayan descargado la aplicación pero nunca he programado en php y no lo comprendo muy bien. 
Desde la consola de firebase ya puedo enviar notificaciones pero para hacerlo desde el servidor rest no sé cómo proceder. 
Alguien podría ayudarme.

Comment: Creo que con este extensión en Yii2 lo podría comenzar a resolver

Comment: https://github.com/OpenSooq/yii2-firebase-notification